# Надо ли склонять в скобках?

Tags: склонение

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли склонять название профессии в скобках в данном предложении? С мая 2017 г. работает инженером (с июля 2020 г. - ведущий инженер / ведущим инженером?) в /название организации/.

Comment: Не надо, иначе придётся писать без скобок.